# Red Object Detector - python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I want to detect red object within a masked area of an image using the histrogram utility of open cv. Here is my method for generating the histrogram - which is packaged into a class;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class red_detector:

def __init__(self, image):

    mask = self.get_mask(image)
    histogram = cv2.calcHist([image], ['r'], mask, [256], [0, 256])
    #some functionality to see whether the volume of red is above a certain amount to denote a red object within the mask


def get_mask(self, image):

    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    mask[100:300, 100:400] = 255
    return mask
```

I would now like to deduce whether or not a red object is within the masked area by accessing the red intensity parameter of the histogram object and seeing if intensities above a certain threshold integrate to a value indicating the presence of the red object, I'm not sure how to access this data from the object.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html), the source code ships with an example of using the color histogram in Python, at `opencv_source/samples/python2/color_histogram.py` where `opencv_source` is the path to the source code you have locally, or [view it on github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/color_histogram.py), and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a histogram is not a best option in this situation. Generally in such cases the simplest (and usually - good enough) option is to:

- Convert image to HSV color space
- Use inRange function to find parts of image with some color
- Find the biggest contour on the result of previous step. If this contour is bigger than some threshold value than this is you object.

Value for inRange function you have to find on you own. Note that in HSV color  model value of hue channel will be the most important for you (because it is responsible for color).

[Here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html) is some example of what i described above.